# Stray Capacitance in a Lithium-ion battery pack casing

Tags: lithium-ion, capacitance

I made a Lithium Ion battery pack for a diy car project using cylindrical cells and observed something interesting. First, I'll lay out the pack details:

Configuration: 1p96s

Max Voltage: 403.2V

Capacity: 10Ah

The simple representation of the design is as follows:

[image]

The grey cylinders are cells which are all 96 in series. All cell connections are on top. The pink material is a thermal potting volume which makes a thermally conducting but electrically insulating contact with the aluminium plate on the bottom shown as green.

Below is a cross section to understand better:
[image]

Now, since the bases of cylindrical cells are also connected to anode internally, I have to make sure that no cell touches the aluminium plate directly. I have checked that and there is no continuity of any cell terminal with the aluminium base plate. However, when I check the voltage between highest positive end of the battery (currently at 350V) and the base plate, I instantly get 175V but it rapidly starts to decrease and settles at lower voltage like 40V or something. After that it decreases super slowly. Same phenomena repeats with every cell, just with different voltage numbers. I have observed both positive voltages, negative voltages and there is one cell which almost has 0V with the base plate. This feels like there is a capacitor that looses charge when I put my multimeter across it to measure the voltage. The potting material has a dielectric constant of 7. The cells bases are in close proximity (few mm) to the base plate.

Is this an obvious phenomena and has some papers/documentaion/articles on it already? I'm lost on the part on how to tackle this. If I mount the pack on chassis, the positive terminal of the pack and the chassis body will now have a voltage too. If someone touches just the chassis, is it dangerous? The base plate mounts to a flat metal body which in turn is part of the chassis.

One more thing, I have tried putting a flat insulation (MDF) between battery and chassis while mounting but now feels like although MDF does prevent the battery base plate and chassis to fall in direct contact but the capacitor observation is still there. The positive terminal and chassis show 160V (which then decreases rapidly again) but there is no continuity between aluminium base plate and the chassis because there is an MDF plate between them.

Can anyone please simplify this and tell me exactly what is happening here. If someone simply knows the phenomena or relevant research material, please drop them and I'll go through it.

Comment: Can you test with AC instead?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't full understand on what do you mean? Should I try measuring AC voltage?

Comment: If you have a stray DC voltage interfering with your isolation measurement, which I don’t understand why you have, consider applying a low AC voltage via a resistor between the terminals you want to measure the resistance between and measure the current by measuring the voltage drop across the resistor. It’s strange to measure DC voltage as a check if you have continuity.

Answer (score 1):

You have an RC equivalent circuit, between each cell and the plate.

The equivalent appears to be parallel (R || C), with R determined by potting material dimensions and leakage current or resistivity, and C determined by dimensions and dielectric constant.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkqnGf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There may be higher order terms (series resistance with the capacitor, or general RLC equivalents at even higher frequencies), but these are undefined as of now.

There is an apparent center point, or node with 0V drop, not because it is connected, but because all the other nodes are pulling up and down equally around that point.

The resistance appears to be quite high, as your meter's internal resistance is typically quite high already (10M?).  You are then measuring the step response as the capacitance is discharged by the meter.  Evidently the Thevenin resistance of all those leakage paths is ~3.4 times the resistance of your meter; if it's a typical 10M DMM, then that's about 34M.  If a VOM, it's likely much smaller.

Whether this resistance is problematic for your isolation system, or performance or overall longevity, I don't know.

---

I don't know offhand the mechanisms of current flow through any kind of potting material; I suppose there is an outside chance it is due to ionic mobility, which would be problematic as it will cause corrosion over time.  If it's ordinary ohmic current flow, it will amount to miniscule self-discharge and nothing else.

There are potting materials that are more moisture-sensitive than others, and therefore could exhibit ionic conduction and electrolytic corrosion, so it seems plausible (given the <s>right</s>wrong material). I put this out there strictly as gross speculation to be confirmed or denied by suitable means.

In short: no one here can really say *why* it's happening, but we can suggest where to go: ask the supplier, or manufacturer, of the potting material.  Preferably they have documentation stating the material is for electrical application, that the resistivity is as expected, it does not exhibit an electrolytic corrosion mechanism, and that you followed the preparation/mixing procedure correctly (without introducing contaminants like dust or salts or moisture, and didn't omit any steps like drying or vacuum or heating).

Comment: Well, the potting material is, as marketed by the company, an insulator. Here's the datasheet link: https://krayden.com/datasheet/lord_sc-309_tds.pdf
I will certainly look into the points raised by you